# How does one diagnose errors in a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get up to speed with AngularJS, coming from a Java background, not Javascript.  I'm used to stepping into a debugger with Eclipse, MSDEV, etc, but not so much used to Google Chrome's dev tools or WebStorm (which I intend to use).  Occasionally, I've made a mistake that apparently is detected upon startup.  I'm guessing it's logged someplace (I hope!), and then silently continues.  Then when I go to the page that would use the controller, I get the

> Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined

error.  Of course, the attached stack trace isn't very helpful.  So the big question is: how do you step into this mess when it actually finds the problem inside the controller, not later when it actually tries to use the controller?

I could post today's issue, but I'd rather have the tools to diagnose this myself than just solve the problem for today.

Comment: Chrome's dev tools. You can tell it to halt on uncaught exceptions, and walk back up the stack. The problem is that there **is no error** in the controller. Specifying invalid values doesn't cause an error until something else attempts to *use* those values, so there is no way to "catch" this in your controller. Asking for a way to catch this error is impossible, because it's not an error at the point you're trying to catch it.

Comment: FWIW, that specific error sometimes occurs when you're trying to define a controller after your application is already `angular.bootstrap()`'ed.

Comment: @meagar, I was afraid that was the case.  So, how is this handled?  There must be some point at which it tries and fails to compile/interpret the controller code and fails.

Comment: Based on my vague assumption, I'd go for `$controllerProvider.register()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install angularJS batarang chrome extension.

Go through  [github repository of angularJS-batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang)

This extension is nice and we can easily debug the angularJS applications

About your error : possible duplicate of [AngularJS/Jade Error: Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined (MEAN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719540/angularjs-jade-error-argument-mycontroller-is-not-a-function-got-undefined)

Comment: I'm not thrilled with batarang, but I suppose that's as good as it's going to get.  Perhaps it will be more useful as I learn more.  The linked dupe is definitely an issue I've had.  It's not today's issue, but that's okay.  It's still important to know!