# Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MainCtrl is not defined,
>   Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

In plnkr it works okey but in my project not.

Any ideas?
http://plnkr.co/edit/rPY6phUgtqavrEDUzhaH?p=preview

I have this in layout:

```
 <li ng-click="changeActiveMenu('Settings');"><a href="../Account/#/PersonalInfo">@Translate("MY_ACCOUNT")</a></li>
```

Comment: reCheck the spell that you have written inside ng-conroller

Comment: i checked few times everything is ok

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Argument is not a function, got undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289236/error-argument-is-not-a-function-got-undefined)

Comment: please make sure it may be very little mistake .. please put your html and controller code so that we can give you better solution

Comment: He provided his fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you did not included your `MainCtrl` in `index.html` file like this

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok then, did you added your MainCtrl in your angular module ?

Comment: var app = angular.module('Online', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'ActivityService', function ($scope, activityService) {....}... yes i am

Comment: ok, while looking into your error it seems like controller not found so, you should add more error trace for get us understand your problem

Comment: i dont know what else to add ?

Answer (score 0):

It is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111831/controller-not-a-function-got-undefined-while-defining-controllers-globally). In angular `1.3.x` versions, you need to register the controller using `module.controller` syntax. Like

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'ActivityService', function ($scope, activityService) { 

//Code

}])
```

Possibly there may be another reason. You're angular script is not loading on the dom. Please use

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.16"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
```

Without any `http` or `https` protocol.

Comment: Its not because of script because other stuff works fine its just when i use like this var MainCtrl = function() .... then error disappear but then highlighting menu is not working

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: MainCtrl is not defined(anonymous function) @ Config.js:16
angular.js:11607 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined that is what i get in console

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719540/angularjs-jade-error-argument-mycontroller-is-not-a-function-got-undefined